# Magento: add new attribute to all products

Tags: magento, attributes, entity-attribute-value

I want to add a new attribute to all products. I have done it with a install script trough

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('catalog_product','test2',array(
    'label'     => 'test2',
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => false,
    'required'  => 0
));
```

But how can I add values to this attribute by

```
$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);
$installer->addAttributeGroup($entityTypeId, 'Default', 'test2', 0);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 10):

This is one of the sample code which I had used to create my own custom Product Attribute:-

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$attrCode = 'test2';
$attrGroupName = 'Test Group';
$attrLabel = 'Test 2';
$attrNote = 'Test Note';

$objCatalogEavSetup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_mysql4_setup', 'core_setup');
$attrIdTest = $objCatalogEavSetup->getAttributeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCode);

if ($attrIdTest === false) {
    $objCatalogEavSetup->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCode, array(
        'group' => $attrGroupName,
        'sort_order' => 7,
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => $attrLabel,
        'note' => $attrNote,
        'input' => 'text',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' => '0',
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'unique' => false,
        'is_configurable' => false,
        'used_for_promo_rules' => true
    ));
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

This is used with the references of these two articles:-

- [Magento Wiki: Installing Custom Attributes with Your Module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module)
- [Mukesh Chapagain Blog: Magento Adding attribute from MySQL setup file](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-adding-attribute-from-mysql-setup-file/)

Also, you will find that I have used the array key "`group`" to mention the Attribute Group Name, where this new custom Attribute will reside. The irony is that mentioning of this key, in the above code sample, automatically creates this Attribute in every Attribute Set found in this Magento.

So you do not need to call any method (like "`addAttributeToSet()`") to add this Attribute to all Attribute Sets.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving - It is better to use `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'core_setup')` instead of `new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup()` to respect Magento's factory system (and therefor rewrite possibilities).

Comment: @7ochem - Well, thanks for your suggestion! But I will not agree to your suggestion fully, because `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'core_setup')` is the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`, whereas I want to have this class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup`. So I've changed that part of the snippet to `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_mysql4_setup', 'core_setup')`. Please suggest, if you find anything more to share.

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving When I was using this piece of code for a script, I found that not all the keys in your array can be used through the `addAttribute()` method, see `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`'s `_prepareValues()` method (`used_for_promo_rules`, `is_configurable`, `visible_on_front`, etc. can't be passed).

Comment: @7ochem - May be the Magento version on which you tested/worked does not support these keys anymore. But definitely, it's a good catch, thanks!

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving - Not sure if this is a 'feature' that's new since your writing of this post, but you can save yourself some code here by configuring your module run the installer as Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup.

(in config.xml)
<global><resources><example_identifier><setup><module>Example_Module</module><class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class></setup></example_identifier></resources></global>

Your installer will then run as that class, and you won't need to instantiate $objCatalogEavSetup.

Comment: @Meogi - Thanks for mentioning this good point! Frankly speaking, I don't quite remember the reason as to why I used this approach, instead of changing the installer class in `config.xml`, but yes we can definitely use this approach (y)

Answer (score 0):

Run this script in your magento root directory.(Change Configuration you need)

```
<?php  

require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();                   

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'snum', array(
             'label'             => 'Serial No',
             'type'              => 'int',
             'input'             => 'text',
             'backend'           => '',
             'frontend'          => '',
             'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'visible'           => true,
             'required'          => false,
             'user_defined'      => false,
             'searchable'        => false,
             'filterable'        => false,
             'comparable'        => false,
             'visible_on_front'  => true,
             'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
             'unique'            => false
));

$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

For Remove Product Attribute

```
<?php  

require_once('app/Mage.php');
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
 $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
 $installer->startSetup();
 $installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'snum');
 $installer->endSetup();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom attribute to the magento backend as shown.If you create the product attribute as module it is easy to move from one database to another.

```
?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(catalog_product, 'featured_product', array(
'group'         => 'General',
'input'         => 'select',
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Featured Product',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
'sort_order'        => 8,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

please refer my tutorial for step by step explanation and **file structure**.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/adding-custom-product-attributes-in-magento/