# Magento adding set of attributes/properties to products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to add something similar to the *Review* system already available on Magento. I mean, I want to add a couple of texts, reviewing capacities and alike. It should have an administration side on the backend to be able to reject/accept/edit those texts. I still do not have all the things clear so I want to ask before I embark into a wrong/closed path.

Should I reuse the existing code by copying core files into local and modifying at will?

Or should I add my own tables and link to EAV model using product ID?

On this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599262/magento-add-new-attribute-to-all-products) the accepted answer posts a code on how to add a new custom attribute to all products. I could use this but I would still need to add the reviews part.

I've searched for a similar functionality but can not find anything.

Comment: Sounds like you want to investigate the Fishpig Wordpress integration first.

Comment: How this could be useful? Could you add some more information?