# How to set default value for an attribute through install script?

Tags: attributes, magento-1.7, product

I have created an attributes using an install script for a custom module. One attribute is a drop-down which only has two options as 'yes','no'. The other attribute is a text field. I need to set default values through this script. I tied the following. But didn't work.

```
$th =  new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup();  
$th->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'credit', array(
            'group' => 'Prices',
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Credit rewards',
            'input' => 'text',
            'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => 'kkkkkkkk', // this is default value. but is's not setting
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple',
        ) );
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following code, i have used on one of my magento installation.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'offer_type', array(
        'backend'       => '',
        'frontend'      => '',
        'class' => '',
        'default'       => 'Wedding Planning',
        'label' => 'Offer type',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type'  => 'int',
        'source'        => '',
        'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'       => 1,
        'required'      => 1,
        'searchable'    => 0,
        'filterable'    => 1,
        'unique'        => 0,
        'comparable'    => 0,
        'visible_on_front' => 1,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 1,
        'user_defined'  => 1,
));
```

you can also add this attribute to a attribute set as follows :

```
$installer->addAttributeToSet('catalog_product', $sSetId, $groupName, 'offer_type');
```

Comment: Can I use $installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup();

Comment: you can use as updated in answer above, if not working you can take reference from this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599262/magento-add-new-attribute-to-all-products

Comment: Thanks a lot. It comes when I add a new product.

Comment: by adding default : "your value" in the array to addAttribute function, i have just tried running my code in my installation and it works like charm adding default value as "Wedding Planning", can you also check whether your config.xml contains correct setup class i.e <setup> <module>Company_Module</module> <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class> </setup>