# Magento - display alternative name for children in grouped products

Tags: php, magento

I would like to display a shortened name for simple product listed under a grouped product in Magento.

Example:

Grouped Product Name: Pony Crochet Hook - 15cm (Plastic)

Simple Product Names:

1. Pony Crochet Hook - 15cm (Plastic) - 5mm
2. Pony Crochet Hook - 15cm (Plastic) - 5.5mm
3. Pony Crochet Hook - 15cm (Plastic) - 6mm
4. Pony Crochet Hook - 15cm (Plastic) - 6.5mm
5. Pony Crochet Hook - 15cm (Plastic) - 7mm
6. etc.

What I would like to display on the grouped product page:

1. 5mm
2. 5.5mm
3. 6mm
4. 6.5mm
5. 7mm
6. etc.

And how this should look in practice: http://www.deramores.com/pony-crochet-hook-plastic-15cm

I thought that the most flexible way of doing this would be to create a new attribute called something like "grouped_product_display_name" and display that on the grouped product page if it is populated or the normal product name if it isn't.

I initially thought some PHP along these lines (apologies if this is way off - I only started trying to write PHP a few days ago and do not have a coding background!):

```
<?php if( ('Grouped Product Display Name') == "" {echo 'grouped_product_display_name';} else {echo $this->__('Product Name');} ?>
```

How would I go about coding this as I am not sure where to change code in Magento to achieve what I am trying to do?!

Many thanks,

Hugh

Answer (score 0):

Add a new attribute to the products entity like 'Short Name':

[Magento: add new attribute to all products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599262/magento-add-new-attribute-to-all-products)

Change the getter in the grouped products template for associated products. In the base theme the template path is:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
```

Instead of:

```
<td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
```

Write:

```
<td>
    <?php $name = ($_item->getShortName()) ? $_item->getShortName() : $_item->getName() ?>
    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($name) ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you.  How would I display the normal name if no data had been entered in the short name attribute?

Comment: I have tried using the following:  
  
    <?php if($_item->getShortName == "" ?>  
    <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getShortName()) ?>  
    <?php else ?>  
    <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>  
  
But get an unexpected ';' parse error.

Comment: Thanks but that produces the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' on Line 67 which is <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($name)) ?>

Comment: @Hugh sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks that has fixed the parsing error but this only shows the normal name even if there is data in the short name.  I have set up an attribute with attribute code: short_name and attribute label: Short Name with a scope of Shop View.  Is this right?

Comment: @Hugh, so you added a short name on the product edit page and it is stored correctly? <?php var_dump($_item->getData()) ?> should show it than.

Comment: yes, it has been added on the product edit page, product saved and cache cleared.

Comment: I have just tried <?php var_dump($_item->getData()) ?> and Short Name is not in the list of attributes.  Any idea what I could have done wrong?

Comment: @Hugh, please renew all indexes.

Comment: @Hugh, sorry, can't help you with that. When indexes are fresh, cache is cleared and the attribute saved, it should appear in the object data. Or maybe I missed something, but I can't see it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else trying to do this here is my solution:

1. Add an attribute with Attribute Code 'short_name' and Attribute Label 'Short Name'. (use the settings from the Name attribute if you are unsure how to set it up correctly apart from which product types this will apply to - see point 2 below)
2. Select which product types you will use this on - I am using it only on Simple products as I do not group any of the other types currently but you may need to use it on other types.
3. Add this attribute below the Name attribute in the General group to whichever attribute sets you want to use this functionality on.
4. Open a simple product(s) which is being used in a grouped product and add the shortened name in the new Short Name field.
5. Save the product(s)
6. Open the following file in your theme folder:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/(base)/(default)/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
   ```
7. Find line:

   ```
   <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
   ```
8. Replace with:

   ```
   <td>
   <?php $shortname = $_item->getShortName() ?>
   <?php $name = $_item->getName() ?>
   <?php if (!is_null($shortname)): ?>
   <?php echo $this->escapeHTML($shortname) ?>
   <?php else: ?>
   <?php echo $this->escapeHTML($name) ?>
   <?php endif ?>
   </td>
   ```
9. Refresh Cache
10. Refresh Indexes

That should now display on the grouped product page the short name if the product has one and the normal name if not.

(I am using Magento 1.9.0.1)